# Boto Route53 or Area53 - How to add multiple ipaddress to a subdomain

Tags: python, dns, boto, amazon-route53

I am trying to add multiple ip address under a sub domain in route 54.  It is enough un the UI and it is easy to add one ip address using area54 or in boto.

```
e.g. master.hui.com
10.130.149.247
10.130.149.248
```

Using area54

```
ipaddress = '10.130.149.247'
entry =  'master.hui.com'
zone = route53.get_zone('hui.com')
add_dns = zone.add_record('A',entry, [ipaddress], ttl='60')
```

In boto:

```
conn = Route53Connection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
changes = ResourceRecordSets(conn, zone_id)

change = changes.add_change("CREATE",sub_domain, "A", 60)
change.add_value(ip_address)
```

So...how do I add two or more ip address under a sub domain using either area53 or boto?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use WRRs.  From the boto CLI:

```
route53 add_record Z1J8BS4AFAKE12 foo.example.com. A 1.2.3.4 60 first 1
route53 add_record Z1J8BS4AFAKE12 foo.example.com. A 5.6.7.8 60 second 2
```

or from the API:

```
change.add_change("CREATE", 'foo', 'A', ttl=60, weight=1, identifier='first')
change.add_change("CREATE", 'foo', 'A', ttl=60, weight=2, identifier='second')
```

See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/WeightedResourceRecordSets.html

Finally, what you are calling a "sub domain" is a "resource record".  "sub domain" implies a zone which left me confused when you sent this question to the boto-users mailing list.

Comment: Thanks...making progress.  I was able to add resource records what I called sub domains.  When I ran the code, there were two seperate records that differ solely by the weight and the set id.  From the aws UI, I can input ip address as a comma delim list but is all on one record.  How does this differ if at all.  Also, with the weights, I assume they will be random at 50/50?

Comment: Never mind...got it with the weights.  Thanks for the solution:)

Answer (score 2):

The original question and accepted answer are quite good but maybe boto's interface has changed since so there are a few issues or details that I bumped into while doing the very same thing.

If you want to add one or more weighted DNSs using boto, the code would be (note that I am using CNAME records instead of A records):

```
conn = Route53Connection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
rrs = ResourceRecordSets(conn, zone_id, comment='for posterity')

change = rrs.add_change('CREATE', fqdn, 'CNAME', ttl=60, identifier='unique', weight=1)
change.add_value(where_the_DNS_should_point_to)

try:
   status = rrs.commit()
except DNSServerError:
   # something went wrong, handle it as you please
   pass

# here you should wait until status is no longer PENDING
```

For completeness' sake, here is the easiest way to delete that very same record:

```
conn = Route53Connection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
zone = conn.get_zone(your_zone_name)

rr = zone.find_records(fqdn, 'CNAME', identifier=('unique', '1'))
# check here that rr is not None
status = zone.delete_record(rr, comment='for posterity')
# here you should wait until status is no longer PENDING
```

Comment: I just used the same method on 2.38.0 and it worked.